# how to invoke a method when the fragment diplayed using popBackStack()

Tags: android, fragment

I want to invoke a method when my fragment re-display from stack using popBackStack() from another fragment

Answer (score 0):

fragment 1:

Store some key value in shared preference where you calling `popBackStack()` in a fragment.

fragment 2:

Get key value of shared preference in `onResume()` --> Then check the getting key value by using `if` loop --> if it's true, execute your method.